# DotNetNuke: URL problem

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke

URL's are posting in address bar however all pages show up as the home page.  I tried to add a document to the documents tab and after seeing inheritance overrides I canceled out of it and now all the pages post the home page.

Comment: So what EXACTLY did you change?

Comment: i clicked on the main website.  went to properties.  clicked on documents tab.  clicked on add.  entered in index.php to add a new document.  clicked on apply.  inheritance overrides popped up.  i canceled out of them then clicked okay.  now its broken.  i must have changed how the pages are built.

Comment: So the override dialogs are for UNCPassword and DefaultDoc and you canceled out.  I agree that it probably shouldn't change either of those values but did you change back the default.php mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNN uses URL rewriting to accomplish its goal.  If anything else takes control of that process before DNN than it will appear as though you can't "go anywhere".

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx